# Get the cache size for an application displayed on the application details page

Tags: android

I need to determine the cache size for my application. I am currently using getCacheDir() called on the application context. However, the size I am getting is less than the cache size displayed on the application details page. I am unable to determine what might be the reason for this discrepancy. How does Android do the cache size calculation?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe real size should computed with this method:

```
getCacheDir().length() + getExternalCacheDir().length()
```

Comment: Thanks! But that doesn't seem to work either as my external cache dir length returns 0.